# How to specify template directory in a cherrypy configuration tool for Mako?

Tags: python, cherrypy

I am trying to use this

http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/Mako

It says I need two_config options for

```
tools.mako.collection_size = 500
tools.mako.directories = "path/to/templates"
```

where do I specify these options and how do I specify these options?

Answer (score 1):

http://cherrypy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html is an excellent place to start

Comment: Your edit caused my feeds to trigger, and I did not notice the age of the answers or question.  Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways to do configuration in CherryPy.  If you don't specify any configuration settings then you are using default values for everything, and you will see a warning that the configuration is empty on starting the cherrypy app.

Your first option is to read in a configuration file.  This is done like this:

```
include cherrypy
include os.path

# Create your application / page handlers here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    global_conf_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__, 'server.conf'))
    cherrypy.config.update(global_conf_file)
    cherrypy.quickstart(Myapp(), config=global_config_file)
```

Those lines can be directly included in the configuration file, with a [global] heading, so the whole file will look like this:

```
[global]
tools.mako.collection_size = 500
tools.mako.directories = 'path/to/templates'
```

If you do not want to put your configuration options into a separate file, you can include them as a dictionary in the main python module, eg like this:

```
include cherrypy

# Create your application / page handlers here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_config = {'/': {'tools.mako.collection_size': 500,
                       'tools.mako.directories': 'path/to/templates'}}

    cherrypy.quickstart(Myapp(), my_config)
```